# How the OS find shared library path in two different linking?:run-time linking (loading) and compile time linking shared library in linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, shared-libraries

i am a little confused about how shared library and the OS works.

1st question : how the OS manages shared libraries?, how they are specified uniquely? by file name or some other(say an ID) things?  or by full path?!

2nd question : i know first when we compile and link codes, the linker need to access the shared library(.so) to perform linking, then after this stage when we execute the compiled program the OS loads the shared library and this libraries may be in different locations(am I wrong?) BUT i do not understand how the OS knows where to look for shared library, is library information (name? path? or what?!) coded in the executable ?

Comment: Look in the directory `/var/lib`, you'll see all the `libXXX.so.*` files

Comment: No, `/var/lib` is not for libraries, it is for persistent systemwide data.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling a program, libraries (other than the language runtime) must be explicitly specified in the build, otherwise they will not be included. There are some standard library directories, so for example you can specify `-lfoo`, and it will automatically look for `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.so` in the various usual directories like `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` etc.

Note, however, that a name like `libfoo.so` is usually a symlink to the actual library file name, which might be something like `libfoo.so.1`. This way, if there needs to be a backward-incompatible change to the ABI (the layout of some structure might change, say), then the new version of the library becomes `libfoo.so.2`, and binaries linked against the old version remain unaffected.

So the linker follows the symlink, and inserts a reference to the versioned name `libfoo.so.1` into the executable, instead of the unversioned name `libfoo.so`. It can also insert the full path, but this is usually not done. Instead, when the executable is run, there is a system search path, as configured in your systemwide `/etc/ld.so.conf`, that is used to find the library.

(Actually, `ld.so.conf` is just the human-readable source for your library search paths; this is compiled into binary form in `/etc/ld.so.cache` for speed, using the `ldconfig` command. This is why you need to run `ldconfig` every time you make changes to the shareable libraries on your system.)

That’s a very simplified explanation of what is going on. There is a whole lot more that is not covered here. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) and [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) are some reference docs that might be useful on the build process. And [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) is a description of the system executable loader.